# Adding textures effectively in 3D game using libGDX

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, textures

I'm writing a 3D game in Java using libGDX. In my game there's a model instance of a room which his walls are just rectangles. I'm tryimg to add an effect of "bullet holes" which are just a texture that appear on the wall when the player shoots at it. I'm trying to figure what the optimal way to implement it? The obvious way is just creating a model instance that built from a single rect with the hole texture for each bullet hole - but this way there will be a draw call for each one of these holes, which is not performance-wise AFAIK.

A piece of code which I create the walls:

```
 Texture wallTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("wall.png"));
    wallTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
    Material wallMaterial = new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(wallTexture));
    MeshPartBuilder meshBuilder = modelBuilder.part("walls", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES,
            VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal |
                    VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates, wallMaterial);
    meshBuilder.setUVRange(0, 0, C.ROOM_SIZE, 3);
    corner00.set(C.ROOM_SIZE, 0, 0);
    corner10.set(0, 0, 0);
    corner11.set(0, 0, 6);
    corner01.set(C.ROOM_SIZE, 0, 6);
    normal.set(0, 1, 0);
    line1000.setNormalDirection(auxVector2.set(0, 1).angle());
    meshBuilder.rect(corner00, corner10, corner11, corner01, normal);
    corner00.set(C.ROOM_SIZE, C.ROOM_SIZE, 0);
    corner10.set(C.ROOM_SIZE, 0, 0);
    corner11.set(C.ROOM_SIZE, 0, 6);
    corner01.set(C.ROOM_SIZE, C.ROOM_SIZE, 6);
    normal.set(-1, 0, 0);
    line1110.setNormalDirection(auxVector2.set(-1, 0).angle());
    meshBuilder.rect(corner00, corner10, corner11, corner01, normal);
    corner00.set(0, C.ROOM_SIZE, 0);
    corner10.set(C.ROOM_SIZE, C.ROOM_SIZE, 0);
    corner11.set(C.ROOM_SIZE, C.ROOM_SIZE, 6);
    corner01.set(0, C.ROOM_SIZE, 6);
    normal.set(0, -1, 0);
    line0111.setNormalDirection(auxVector2.set(0, -1).angle());
    meshBuilder.rect(corner00, corner10, corner11, corner01, normal);
    corner00.set(0, 0, 0);
    corner10.set(0, C.ROOM_SIZE, 0);
    corner11.set(0, C.ROOM_SIZE, 6);
    corner01.set(0, 0, 6);
    normal.set(1, 0, 0);
    line0001.setNormalDirection(auxVector2.set(1, 0).angle());
    meshBuilder.rect(corner00, corner10, corner11, corner01, normal);
    Model levelModel = modelBuilder.end();
    levelModelInstance = new ModelInstance(levelModel);
```

This part occurs only once upon loading the level. The bullet holes are supposed to appear in-game.

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: Added a relevant piece of code.

Comment: you should either rebake the texture or use sprites for it